# Localize button Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

For example I've got an app which has a textLabel and a button which are firstly set as:

```
mainLabel.attributedText = "labelNewText".uppercased()   
mainButton.titleLabel?.attributedText = "buttonNewText".uppercased()
```

Then I've created a Localization file, where I set a some values for a German language:

```
"labelNewText" = "Etikette";
"buttonNewText" = "Taste";
```

And rewrote set ups for label and button like:

```
mainLabel.attributedText = "\(NSLocalizedString("labelNewText", comment: ""))".uppercased()
mainButton.titleLabel?.attributedText = "\(NSLocalizedString("buttonNewText", comment: ""))".uppercased()
```

Though, right after after I change my phone language setting to German, the translation only works for a Label but is not working for button. What am I doing wrong and how to localise button titleLabel?

Comment: For `mainLabel`, you don't have to interpolate the string into a string, you could let it be: `mainLabel.attributedText = NSLocalizedString("labelNewText", comment: "").uppercased()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `UIButton`'s `setAttributedTitle:forState:` instead of trying to manipulate the text label itself. So for example:

```
mainButton.setAttributedTitle(myAttributeString, forState: .normal)
```